# flutter Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3)

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, jsondecoder

I want to decode my data from storage (shared preference) and use it in my variables.
but I got this error:

```
error : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3)
```

here is my code :

```
     getIt<Storage>().get("data_${id}").then((value) {
             // value is not empty
              try {
                List<Map> temp = jsonDecode(value ?? '[]') as List<Map>;
                myNotifier.value = temp;
              } catch (e) {
                print("error : $e");
              }
            });
```

can anyone help me please how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the value of  `value`?

Comment: data of my storage

Comment: *Exactly* what is the content of the string referenced by `value`?  Clearly it is not valid JSON.